# SQL Count Distinct IDs with condition

Tags: sql

I would like to make a query in which I can count the number of IDs which have at least 1 true value for a given column, and do this for multiple columns at once.

For example, I have a database like this:

```
Table1    
Name    col_1    col_2
A       true     true
A       false    true
B       false    false
C       true     false
C       true     false

Table2    
Name    ID
A       1
B       2
C       3
```

I essentially would like to count how many IDs have a certain column true (the resulting output appearing as follows):

```
Row    col_1_true    col_2_true
1      2             1
```

For a single column, I can do:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ID, col_1) as col_1_true
FROM table1, table2
  WHERE table1.Name = table2.Name
        col_1 = true
```

But I want to get all desired counts in my final output from a single query (as my actual dataset has many columns I would like to query on a regular basis), so something like the following:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ID, col_1 = true) as col_1_true
  COUNT(DISTINCT ID, col_2 = true) as col_2_true
FROM table1, table2
  WHERE table1.Name = table2.Name
```

I've tried a number of methods, which are along the lines of:

```
SUM(DISTINCT ID, CASE WHEN col_1 = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

which throws and error (too many arguments for function SUM), or

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN col_1 = true
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AS col_1_true,

  SUM(
    CASE WHEN col_2 = true
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AS col_2_true

FROM table1, table2
  WHERE table1.Name = table2.Name
  GROUP BY table2.ID
```

Which does not provide the proper output. It's output is:

```
Row    col_1_true    col_2_true
1      1             1
2      0             1
3      0             0
4      1             0
5      1             0
```

I'm thinking I may have to bring in subqueries and/or subtables, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Your `SUM(CASE WHEN)` method is correct as long as you use proper syntax.  It's called "*conditional aggregation*".

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: col_1 and col_2 data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in tsql it would be something like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN col_1 = true
    THEN table2.ID END)
  AS col_1_true,

  COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN col_2 = true
    THEN table2.ID END)
  AS col_2_true

FROM table1, table2
  WHERE table1.Name = table2.Name
```